# NGINX HTML5 routing proxy pass

Tags: nginx

How to make an internal redirect to a CDN with NGINX, if the URL starts with /app?

I have an application living on www.test.sphingx.com/app

And this is my NGINX config for redirecting to the CDN.

```
location /app {
  proxy_pass http://cdn/app;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
}
```

All works fine, until Angular changes the route URL for example to www.test.sphingx.com/app/users

if the user refreshes the page, NGINX will try to redirect to http://cdn/app/users, but should really be internally redirecting to just http://cdn/app because thats where the Frontend files are. now it will give a 404.

So how can I 'internally' load the frontend files from http://cdn/app/ if the url is /app/1/2/3/3/4/5/ while not changing the url in the browser?

Thanks

```
location /app {
  proxy_pass http://cdn/app;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 404 =200 /app;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_intercept_errors on;` and `error_page 404 = /app;`?

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith thanks for the answer! I tried but it shows a blank page without any error (just a 200) you can see it on https://test.sphingx.com/app and try to refresh after Angular changes the route to login. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` URL ?

Comment: Hi @IVOGELOV, thanks for the answer! It ends up in a redirect loop unfortunately with a trailing slash

Comment: Why ? The CDN is not supposed to redirect back to nginX, right ?

Comment: Correct, it only holds some static files that should be loaded.. The CDN has a directory 'app' that holds all the files.

Comment: Its NGINX thats gets into a redirect loop

Comment: @RichardSmith, it works now, but then the url is 'lost' after /app